# How do you call a word that is the result of merging two words?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a word that is the result of merging two words together?

For example, Maroon + Tuna = Marona, or Crab + Apple = Crapple, or Choking + Holding = Chokehold

1. The word I am looking for is not "nick name"
2. The word I am looking for is not acronym e.g. Laser as "light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The word is *portmanteau*.**

It originally (and still) means a large suitcase. In through the Looking Glass, Lewis Carroll introduced a second meaning:

> a word or morpheme whose form and meaning are derived from a blending of two or more distinct forms (as smog from smoke and fog)

**First appearance**

In reference to the word *mimsy*, which is a portmanteau of *miserable* and *flimsy*,

> "You see it's like a portmanteau—there are two meanings packed up into one word."

The word is "like a portmanteau" because one word carries multiple contents, like a suitcase, and because the word *portmanteau* itself, is a portmanteau.

Comment: Does Jabberwocky make sense if some of the words are viewed as portmanteau? https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/42916

Comment: @BeachedWhale I think yes, but it takes a good bit of work to parse. I also though find that the portmanteaus are pretty good at carrying meaning even when they don't carry sense